# Examples of Functions f and g such that lim f(x)g(x) exist but lim f(x) and lim g(x) doesnt

Tags: limits

what such cases exist?

Such that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)g(x)$ exists even though neither $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ nor $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exists.

Comment: Do you really mean $x\to b$ in the $g(x)$ limit?

Comment: No no it's x->a

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $f(x)=g(x)=1$ when $x$ is rational but $-1$ when $x$ is irrational. In this example you can let $a$ (the approached point) be anything, e.g. $a=0.$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=1+\tan(x)^2$$
$$g(x)=\cos(x)^2$$
$$\text{ So that we have: } \text{ }\text{ } f(x)g(x)=\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2=1$$
$$\text{ But neither} \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) \text{ nor} \lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) \text{ exist }$$
$$\text{ While}\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)g(x)=1 \text{ does exist}$$